# Unique visitor counter for Express.js

Tags: express, for-loop, unique, counter, visitor-pattern

I ran into a problem that I cannot do. I will be glad if you help me.

I am writing a website in blog style with node.js. But I couldn't find a way to measure how many people viewed blog posts.

I want a system like this;

> When someone enters the site, they will be counted as a visitor and 1 will be added to the counter.

> When the same person re-enters the site, this time she will not count as a visitor. Number will not be added to the counter

Comment: To do the counter you can do in your server side index.js file a counter variable and always when one of your endpoints get reached then increment this variable.
For the unique part you probably have to check the IP-Address.

Comment: I do as you say, but when the user changes the IP address and refreshes the page, it saves it again.

Comment: You mean when he use a vpn? He cannot change its global ip address.
Another solution would be maybe with cookies but when the cookie expires it will also count again

Comment: So how can I get the global ip address?

Comment: it should be in your request object req.ip

Answer (score 0):

Use [express-visitor-counter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-visitor-counter)...

```
const express = require('express');
const expressSession = require('express-session');
const expressVisitorCounter = require('express-visitor-counter');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

(async () => {
  const dbConnection = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', { useUnifiedTopology: true });
  const counters = dbConnection.db().collection('counters');

  const app = express();
  app.enable('trust proxy');
  app.use(expressSession({ secret: 'secret', resave: false, saveUninitialized: true }));
  app.use(expressVisitorCounter({ collection: counters }));
  app.get('/', async (req, res, next) => res.json(await counters.find().toArray()));
  app.listen(8080);
})();
```